# String manipulation via recursion (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have incoming strings that are formatted using some bracket notation method I haven't seen before (I assume to compress size). Understanding the method itself is straightforward but I'm having trouble turning that into code it out.

---

Here is a simple example of an incoming string: `'ADFAS[AA,BT]'`

This string needs to be parsed so that it results in the array: `['ADFASAA', 'ADFASBT']`.

It is important that order is maintained in the resulting array. I'm open to any nice clean answer although I like the idea of an elegant recursive method here. I'm not having luck.

---

Here is a more complicated example:
`'INGFKQRRG[I5EEOR[T,U,V,W],Y5ECOR[T,U]]'`

Which should yield the result:

```
[
  'INGFKQRRGI5EEORT', //--
  'INGFKQRRGI5EEORU', //  \
  'INGFKQRRGI5EEORV', //  / - these are from the first nested level block and its nested letter endings
  'INGFKQRRGI5EEORW', //--

  'INGFKQRRGY5ECORT', //--\
  'INGFKQRRGY5ECORU', //--/ - these are from the second nested level block and its nested letter endings
]
```

---

The incoming strings may have multiple nested levels. Ex: `'GMZTAOSIHI[2Q,3[A,Q],4A]'`
Which should yield:

```
[
  'GMZTAOSIHI2Q',

  'GMZTAOSIHI3A',
  'GMZTAOSIHI3Q',

  'GMZTAOSIHI4A'
]
```

---

Here's the approach I've been taking so far:

A function that finds the outermost bracketed substr

```
function getInnerBracket(s) {
    const sBracket = s.indexOf('['),
          eBracket = s.lastIndexOf(']');

    return t.slice(sBracket + 1, eBracket);
}
```

Then I can test the string to see if it has a `],` which indicates that within the returned string has multiple parts, some of which may have more nested items.

```
function testForSubItems(s) {
    return /\],/.test(s)
        ? s.split('],')
        : s;
}
```

At this point I feel very stuck because I can't figure out how to write one wrapper function to recursively keep track of when to pass it back down to these two helper functions. Every attempt just ends up with logic holes and I'm stuck.

Comment: Not an answer, but given that you may have deeply nested text content, JS regex probably isn't the solution for your problem.

Comment: _"I'm open to any nice clean answer"_ - And we are open for your attempt to solve this on your own ;)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen From all examples I've seen so far, they don't seem to ever go past 5-6 nested levels. On average they have ~2 nested levels.

Comment: @Andreas I have been trying for the past ~2hrs :) thanks for the encouragement tho!

Comment: Then you've missed to add those attempts. SO is not meant to be a free coding service.

Comment: Yea thanks, this isn't my first day here. My solutions all mess up at different edge cases and are not useful.

Comment: From what I can see, you're probably going to have write some kind of expression parser to handle this in the general case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ive been trying a method that gets the bounds of nested strings inside '[]' then checking to see if there are more nested '[]' but the commas are throwing me off - they're meant to be a place to split but I can't figure out how to accurately tell when

Comment: You should consider showing your attempt. It's possible that there could be some minor logic flaw. Overall this is going to be next to impossible with regex alone and you'll need to build a parser which evaluates the string one character at a time. `var chars = weird_string.split('');` will be of interest.

Comment: Tip: This can be treated as a MULTIDIMENTIONAL ARRAY. Now just iterate over the array, adding all cell texts to your string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursive `regex` solution:

```js
let A = 'INGFKQRRG[I5EEOR[T,U,V,W],Y5ECOR[T,U]]';

const expand = (s) => {
  s = s.replace(
    /([^[,]+)\[([^[\]]+)\]/g, 
    (_, w, px) => px.split(',').map(c => w+c).join(',')
  );
  return s.includes('[') ? expand(s) : s.split(',');
}

console.log(expand(A))
console.log(expand('GMZTAOSIHI[2Q,3[A,Q],4A]'))
```

Comment: Wow. I am blown away. This is so concise and clear. Thank you! Tested on one more nested level just to make sure and it worked perfectly! (Ex. `'GMZTAOSIHI[2Q,3[A,Q,C[B,E]],4A]'`)

Comment: @AdamMoisa, happy to help!